# custom font fails when i type a r t

Tags: fonts, truetype

I have created a custom font.

I have a very specific issue when I type the letters a r t in that order.

```
ar - works 
rt - works
rtX - any other letter after works
Xrt - any other letter before works
```

however typing art results in a `[]` t - with the `[]` representing that annoying square when a font fails.

Obviously I know this isn't 'programming' per say - but I am guessing it is some random fault with the unicode characters appearing in that order that is causing it and there might just be someone on here smart enough to help me.

Font created in illustrator - compiled with Bird Font.

NO other character combinations seems to cause this problem :-P

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't seem to find the root cause of the problem - tried creating a different font from the characters etc. etc.

If anyone has this weird bug the 'hack' to fix it is to set up a ligature for the character sequence causing problems.

This seems to have fixed the problem with my font as the `art` ligature over-rides whatever was causing the `art` sequence to fail (so I am guessing it was some weird language setting trying to use a character I haven't created as part of the font).